# Kernel died when I add parameter class_weight to a CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kernel

Basically the kernel dies whenever 'class_weight' is inserted in it. I have ran the exact same model but without class_weight and had no problem. I'm using jupyter notebook (6.2.0) on Macbook Pro M1 chip 16gb RAM, python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.4.
Thank you

Comment: please show code. I use class_weight often and it works fine

Comment: @GerryP do you have the same machine as I do?

Comment: nope windows pc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems related to M1 processors. I ran into the same issue on my Mac Mini (M1) on both this exact same tutorial and on another model I was working on. I filed https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/275.

Comment: I have the same issue using Mac M1. Did you find any solution for this so far?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are calculating class_weight incorrectly. Let say you have 4 classes, labeled 0,1,2,3. For each class assume the sample distribution is

```
class     samples
  0         500
  1         1000
  2         1500
  3         2000
```

now what you do is find the class that has the LARGEST number of samples call it max_samples. Then the class weight for a given class is given
weight= max_samples/ samples in the class. Class weight is a dictionary. For the example above

```
max_samples=2000
class_weight= {0: 2000/500, 1: 2000/1000, 2:2000/1500, 3:2000/2000}
class_weight= {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 1.33333, 4:1.0}
```

For class 0 which has the least samples, a class weight of 4 is used in the loss function to offset the fact that class 4 has 4 times as many samples./